# Understanding GTFS service times

Tags: search, gtfs

I have a problem with the understanding of the gtfs file format. Or maybe there is an error in that data. There is a gtfs file from a public transportation agency called "Verkehrsverbund Mittelthüringen" (VMT). This data is accessible at https://transitfeeds.com/p/verkehrsverbund-mittelth-ringen/1080/latest/routes.

For example: I have taken the trip with the ID `9782458` ([trips.txt](https://openmobilitydata-data.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/public/feeds/verkehrsverbund-mittelth-ringen/1080/20191206/original/trips.txt)).

```
2841_0,45,9782458,"Erfurt, ThÃ¼ringenhalle","",0,,,,
```

This has the service ID `45` with the specification

```
45,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20191101,20200229
```

Additionally here are the entries for the [celendar_dates.txt](https://openmobilitydata-data.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/public/feeds/verkehrsverbund-mittelth-ringen/1080/20191206/original/calendar_dates.txt)

```
45,20191104,1
45,20191111,1
45,20191118,1
45,20191125,1
45,20191202,1
45,20191209,1
45,20191216,1
45,20191105,1
45,20191112,1
45,20191119,1
45,20191126,1
45,20191203,1
45,20191210,1
45,20191217,1
45,20191106,1
45,20191113,1
45,20191120,1
45,20191127,1
45,20191204,1
45,20191211,1
45,20191218,1
45,20191107,1
45,20191114,1
45,20191121,1
45,20191128,1
45,20191205,1
45,20191212,1
45,20191219,1
45,20191101,1
45,20191108,1
45,20191115,1
45,20191122,1
45,20191129,1
45,20191206,1
45,20191213,1
45,20191220,1
```

Does this mean, that the service is available all times, except from the 1st November 2019 to the 29th February 2020? My Problem now is the output of the search engine [tansitfeeds.com](https://transitfeeds.com/p/verkehrsverbund-mittelth-ringen/1080/latest/route/2841_0/20191114). It says the trip with the ID `9782458` is available at the 14th November 2019. Which is contary to my understanding of the data: the trip won't be available in November. Where is the clue I missed? Or is there an error in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you pasted indicates that service ID `45` runs on zero days of the week (that's what all those zeros mean), so the start and end dates in the same line don't really mean anything.

If this service actually does run on Nov. 14, this could be represented in the `calendar_dates.txt` file, which is usually used to represent service changes for special dates.

EDIT: the data you added from `calendar_dates.txt` does indeed show that service `45` has been added for date `20191114`.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I've updated the question and added more information from the data. As far as I can see, there is no exception for the 14th of November. However, transitfeeds tells me, that the trip takes place at the 14th November (see https://transitfeeds.com/p/verkehrsverbund-mittelth-ringen/1080/latest/trip/9782458). From my view, the trip should not be available. Do you have any idea?

Comment: In the data you have copied from the `calendar_dates.txt` file, I see this line: `45,20191114,1`. The `1` indicates that service ID `45` is indeed active for Nov. 14 (quoting from the GTFS reference: "Service has been added for the specified date.").

Comment: Thank you for your additional eye. Now I understand the format :)